# "foo" is not a function using Jest to test a component method

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following component:

```
export class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  boolToTitleCase = (value) => {
    return value ? 'True' : 'False';
  };

render () {
  return (
    <div></div>
  );
}
```

Then in my test I do this:

```
import {boolToTitleCase, MyComponent} from './MyComponentFile';
// blah blah
  describe('Rendering', () => {
    it('boolToTitleCase renders true to True and false to False', () => {
        expect(boolToTitleCase(true)).toBe('True');
        expect(boolToTitleCase(false)).toBe('False');
    })
});
```

I get this error:

```
    TypeError: (0 , MyComponent.boolToTitleCase) is not a function

      53 |     });
      54 |     it('boolToTitleCase renders true to True and false to False', () => {
    > 55 |         expect(boolToTitleCase(true)).toBe('True');
         |                ^
      56 |         expect(boolToTitleCase(false)).toBe('False');
      57 |     });
      58 |
```

How do I access that method directly?

Answer (score 0):

The function you are trying to test is part of the component itself and not being exported so you can't import it directly. Having said that, looking at the implementation there isn't anything stopping you from moving it into it's own exportable function

```
export function boolToTitleCase = value => value ? 'True' : 'False';

export class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div></div>;
  }
}
```

That way your test wouldn't have to change.